# Install WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP on Windows x64

Tags: php, web-services, wamp, 64-bit, wso2

I'm using WampServer ( PHP 5.3.8, Apache 2.2.21, 64-Bit ) on Windows 7 and tried to install "WSO2 Framework for PHP 2.1.0" (wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32) exactly as told in documentation. But unfortunately i couldn't succeed. And i keep getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
    'c:/_wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/wsf.dll' -
     %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

PHP is working fine, but no success on wsf.

Any suggestions?

PS. I think php can't load the dll because it's 32bit, but I couldn't find any 64bit binaries out there.

Comment: Any progress on this?  I'm trying to install the WSO2 for PHP 2.1, and I'm not getting anywhere either.  I get PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\wsf.dll'.  It's there, I can watch assemblies being loaded in process monitor.  It is x64 windows, but I'm running 5.4.6 on IIS.

Comment: no progress at all.. i think its a dependency problem, maybe libxml or xslt... it doesn't like those came with php. btw, i've also failed compiling on FreeBSD... now, i'm considering to write a java proxy for my soap needs.